# Unity removed after installing KDE SC 4.10

Tags: unity, kde4

I wanted to try the new version of kubuntu desktop (KDE SC 4.10) on my Ubuntu 12.10, so I did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

installation went without problems, I ended unity session and logged into KDE. But when I wanted to log back into unity, this option wasn't there, there were just options Gnome Classic and KDE. I found out that Unity was somehow removed, so I tried installing it back on with `sudo apt-get install unity`, but I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-5 (= 6.12.0+bzr2800sruubuntu0+808) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libunity-protocol-private0 (>= 6.12.0) but 6.10.0+bzr188sruubuntu0+152 is to be installed
         Recommends: unity-lens-music but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-lens-shopping but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: unity-lens-video but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get -f install` but it did nothing. I know that I'm one of the few people, who want Unity back instead of getting rid of it, but is there a way to fix this and bring Unity back?

EDIT: I also tried `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but I got a similar error, because one of its dependencies is Unity, which cannot be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And after:

```
$sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

But in my experiences install KDE with Unity don't work...

Sorry for my english, i'm learning.